# Unittesting python flask falsk-restplus application

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, python-unittest, flask-restplus

I recently build a python backend with flask and flask-restplus and I now want to properly test my code. I'm using the **unittest** framework for testing and have a setUp method as follows:
`def setUp(self):
    self.app = controller.app.test_client()
    self.app.testing = True`

**My Probblem is:**
When testing one of the endpoints, it works like a charm but the endpoint starts an analysis which lasts more than 30 minutes.

**My Question:**
I would like to know how i can properly destroy the test_client() created, in my tearDown method so the analysis will only run as long as the test method is asserting things.

I appreciate you all reading this and trying to help and looking forward to your answers

Greetz

**EDIT**
I just noticed that the reason the test is still running after my test methods returned green is because the controller app is still running inside the test container. So the actual question would be:
How can i close the flask controller inside a test class with my tearDown method

Comment: What your unit tests seem to miss is mocking of the dependencies. If you test calls a function outside the testing scope (which is small for unit tests) it should be mocked. See the [mock module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) for details.

Comment: yeah i got that you are right i don't mock atm e.g. database etc. but thats not the source of my problem. the test itself succeeds but i can't tear down the app properly because inside self.app the controller started a threaded analysis lasting 30 mins

Comment: Then you have to mock that thread.

Comment: just edited the question. I actually don't want to mock the thread because i want the test to invoke the scripts as it does in real.